# Differentiable at one point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f$ id differentiable at $c\in]a,b[$.

Given $\epsilon>0$ show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(v)-f(u)-f'(c)(v-u)|\le\epsilon(v-u)$ whenever $c-\delta<u<c<v<c+\delta$.

I started by stating that we know that $|(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$. Since $c-\delta<u<c<v<c+\delta$, then $|(f(u)-f(c))/(u-c)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$ and $|(f(v)-f(c))/(v-c)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$.

What can I do to get $|(f(u)-f(v))/(u-v)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Write $|f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)*(x-c)|<\epsilon |x-c|$ for two values of $x$, namely $u$ and $v$, and see if you can add the two inequalities.

Comment: "...stating that we know ...."... **as long as** $\;|x-c|<\delta\;$ for some $\;\delta>0\;$ whose existence is guaranteed by the existence of the limit, and also for each $\;\epsilon >0 \;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that for $c<v<c+\delta$ then:
$$-\varepsilon<\frac{f(v)-f(c)}{v-c}-f'(c)<\varepsilon$$
And for $c-\delta<u<c$ then:
$$-\varepsilon<\frac{f(c)-f(u)}{c-u}-f'(c)<\varepsilon$$

Given that the numerators are positive you have:
$$
-\varepsilon(v-c)<f(v)-f(c)-f'(c)(v-c)<\varepsilon(v-c) \\
-\varepsilon(c-u)<f(c)-f(u)-f'(c)(c-u)<\varepsilon(c-u)
$$

Now, add each term of the inequalities.